# Inno Setup Script For MySQL 5.7 silent install

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I want to silent install MySQL 5.7 from Inno Setup so i have use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827660/how-to-do-a-silent-install-of-mysql-in-inno-setup), but this for MySQL 5.5 not for 5.7. I have [MySQInstallerConsole](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/MySQLInstallerConsole.html)  form command prompt to check if it work. But this is also not installing application.

Run below command :-

```
MySQLInstallerConsole install server;5.7.19;x64 -silent

Output :- 
No changes required for MySQL Server 5.7.19
```

Result :- MySQL not installed

Anyone used MySQL 5.7 installation with Inno Setup?

Comment: Do you mean that you have tried to use `mysql-installer-community-5.7.19.0.msi` in the code from [How to do a silent install of mysql in inno setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18827660/850848) and it did not work? Why? What did it do wrong?

Comment: its installing MySQL installer not MySQL server. i think there is something has change in MySQL 5.7

Comment: Did you try **Parameters: "--initialize";** instead of **--install**?

Comment: I am getting --initialize is not a supported action.

Comment: Did you try to remove -silent and look for a verbose answer?
It seems that you already have installed 5.7.19...