# How to create an installer for app Java swing using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, windows-installer

How to distribute an app desktop using Java and MySQL (and hibernate)? The biggest problem is how to create the schema automatically, I believe. I want to create an installer for my app, basically.

Thanks.

Comment: So you're going to install mysql on client's PC which will be used only by your application? Why not use some embedded database?

Comment: But how to create the schema?

Comment: Hibernate can do that for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Is this an open source project oris it a commercial application? If the latter, theny ou need to purchase a commercial mysql license before you can distribute mysql with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm looking for some options, but I found somethig that solves my problem:

1. hibernate can create schemas automatically ([Hibernate auto create database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069687/hibernate-auto-create-database)) using

   ```
   createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
   ```
2. MySql can be installed in silent mode (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html)

   ```
   shell> msiexec /i mysql-5.5.65.msi /quiet
   ```

I'm looking now for packaging all of this ([Is there a good alternative to Install Shield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135934/is-there-a-good-alternative-to-install-shield)). But, I consider the problem solved for me. Thanks for all.

EDIT: Inno will be the winner, for my problem ([How to do a silent install of mysql in inno setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827660/how-to-do-a-silent-install-of-mysql-in-inno-setup))

EDIT2: Unfortunately, silent mode is not supported for the latest version of MySQL; at least not the way I expected. I got too close, but couldn't set all the parameters using the command line. As a final solution, I changed to another database with this support.